# How to set up a Windows Docker Container with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, docker

Context:
Linux SQL Docker containers don't support FileStreams, so this is a no-go the Database I wish to restore (which uses Varbinaries) we're trying to remove them, but short term, we need to keep them and can't lose the data in them or render the columns non-functional.

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
```

Windows SQL Docker seems to be end of life and the repo has been taken down

```
microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer
```

So that leaves me with one perceived option... Build my own Windows Container and install SQL Server manually. So using SQL Server Core 2019

```
mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore
```

---

From here I tried to source examples of this being done by others, to limited success. This gave me a good basis of a DockerFile to start from:

[Setup Guide I was following](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5698/create-sql-server-on-windows-docker-container-using-dockerfile-part-6/)

```
#Step 1: Start from base image mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore
#Step 2: Create temporary directory to hold SQL Server 2016 installation files
RUN powershell -Command (mkdir C:\SQL2016Dev_SP2)
#Step 3: Copy SQL Server 2016 installation files from the host to the container image
COPY \SQL2016Dev_SP2 C:/SQL2016Dev_SP2
#Step 4: Install SQL Server 2016 via command line
RUN C:/SQL2016Dev_SP2/SETUP.exe /Q /ACTION=INSTALL /FEATURES=SQLENGINE /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER 
/SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD="y0urSecUr3PAssw0rd" /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\System" 
/AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\System" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\Administrators" 
/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=1 /TCPENABLED=1 /UPDATEENABLED=False
#Step 5: Set SQL Server service to automatic
RUN powershell -Command (Set-Service MSSQLSERVER -StartupType Automatic)
#Step 6: Remove SQL Server installation media folder
RUN powershell -Command (Remove-Item -Path C:/SQL2016Dev_SP2 -Recurse -Force) 
#Step 7: Switch shell to PowerShell in preparation for running script Start.ps1
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
#Step 8: Copy Start.ps1 to image on root directory
COPY \start.ps1 /
#Step 9: Set current working directory for script execution
WORKDIR /
#Step 10: Run PowerShell script Start.ps1, passing the -ACCEPT_EULA parameter with a value of Y
CMD .\start.ps1 -ACCEPT_EULA "Y" -Verbose
```

[Start.ps1 source](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/blob/master/windows/mssql-server-windows/start.ps1)

---

#Step 4 gave me issues in that many of the parameters in step 4 aren't supported

[Reference list of SQL accepted params from Microsoft for SQL 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
The setting 'features' specified is not recognized.
```

This is repeat for: 'instancename', 'securitymode', 'sapwd', 'sqlsvcaccount', 'agtsvcaccount', 'sqlsysadminaccounts', 'tcpenabled','updateenabled'

Using `/?` on the downloaded installer (sql server 2022, developer) confirms the reduced list of accepted parameters.

Stripping out the parameters leaves a Container with a SQL server install, but no SA user, meaning no user to log in with.

My goal is to have a Windows Docker container, Running SQL Server, with an account to log into for a destructible test environment.

Comment: Microsoft withdrew their attempt, and support, for SQL Server in Windows Containers a few years ago. There is no alternative that would lead to a supported scenario.

Comment: I don't understand why NTFS is a no go; `varbinary` values work fine in a non-NTFS storage environment.

Comment: @ThomA from what I understand, the secondary Datavolumes that VarBinaries are written to, ndf's are in NTFS format, making restoring them on a Linux env in the range of difficult to impossible

Comment: And I'm not looking for anything supported, just stopgap until we can get our VarBinaries converted to non-FileStream (NTFS) formats, then we'll be wholly using a Linux container

Comment: You mean FILESTREAM? It uses varbinary but varbinary exists outside of FILESTREAM

Comment: Multiple files are supported on Linux without an issue. The problem is Filestream isn't supported in SQL Server on Linux; thats a documented limitation. That you can't use NTFS has nothing to do with the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that Windows Server Core 2019/2022 docker images do not have support for FILESTREAM either and any attempt to enable them in SQL server management via WMI would silently fail. So in order to achieve what I was looking to do, I would have to use a full Windows Server installation.

Looks like I'll be taking the route of changing my VarBinaries to another structure that doesn't implement FileStreams.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to create SQL server image in windows container using the following instructions. Hope this can help!

https://tobiasfenster.io/ms-sql-server-in-windows-containers

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: https://github.com/IssacKramer/mssql-image-v2022-CU11

Working SQL Server 2022 + CU11 on WINDOWS container.

From the README:

> Update 02.07.2024:
>
> This version was updated by me, Isaac Kramer based on the work of Tobias. This version update the container to Sql Server 2022 + Cumulative Update 11 (CU11) Build version 16.0.4105.2 for WINDOWS(!) container.
>
> The steps for build are explained in the Dockerfile.
>
> You need 3 setup folders on the host to be ready for the build as seen in the Dockerfile:
>
> 1. The main SQL Server 2022 express setup media extracted so that the root SETUP.EXE will be in 'SQLSetupMedia/SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU/' folder.
> 2. The CU update (in this case CU11) EXE file (don't need to be extracted) in '\SQLSetupMedia\CU\CU11\SQLServer2022-KB5032679-x64.exe'
> 3. Due to strange bug that the servercore 2022 image don't have old server controls (used to be at 1809) you must have The Missing Server control files/folders - which is a bunch of folders which include old control dll's under 'Missing' folder. as explaind in here: microsoft/mssql-docker#540. So 4 folders needs to be in the folder '\SQLSetupMedia/CU/CU11/Missing/' to fix this strange bug i mentioned there. you can get them from an old sql server installation from the GAC folder. For convenience for the public i uploaded a zip file with all the folders to just drop it there. zip file: OldServerControlsFolders.zip
>
> SQL Server 2022 express (I believe it will work the same for Dev/Ent) on WINDOWS container build 16.0.4105.2 (!)
> Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

As stated by @Ben Bowen in previous post, even if using Windows Container, FILESTREAM is not supported. It will give strange errors when restoring backup with FILESTREAM such as path not found or permission denied.